# Uncaught ReferenceError: DocxGen is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I am writing a application to load docx content into textarea html.
I am using Docxgen to do it but receive the following error message:
Uncaught ReferenceError: DocxGen is not defined
    at index.html:25
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (jszip-utils.js:92).
Can someone help me with this error.
Here is the code:

```js
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/build/docxgen.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/file-saver.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jszip-utils.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    loadFile("C:/Path/Test.docx",function(err,content){
        var doc= new DocxGen(content);  
        text=doc.getFullText();
       $("textarea").val(text);   
});

function loadFile(url,callback){
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url,callback);
}
});
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Call the function on `$(document).ready()`, to ensure Docxgen has been loaded and parsed.

Comment: I tried your solution but doesn`t work, i got the same error message.